# AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'heal'

Tags: python

Hello guys I'm really new to python -- or any coding for that matter! Anyway, I'm trying to make a simple text based RPG game, I'm nowhere near finished but I'm having problems creating a healing system. Everything works until I try using the heal spell and it returns the error in the title. No I kinda know what it's trying to tell me is wrong but I've no idea how to remedy it. Any help will be appreciated but please keep in mind I'm a massive newbie when it comes to coding.

Thankyou.

```
from classes.game import Person, bcolors
from classes.magic import Spell

# Create Black Magic
fire = Spell("Fire", 10, 100, "black")
thunder = Spell("Thunder", 10, 100, "black")
blizzard = Spell("Blizzard", 10, 100, "black")
meteor = Spell("Meteor", 20, 200, "black")
quake = Spell("Quake", 14, 140, "black")

# Create White Magic
cure = Spell("Cure", 12, 120, "white")
cura = Spell("Cura", 18, 200, "white")

# Instantiate People
player = Person(460, 65, 60, 34, [fire, thunder, blizzard, meteor, cure,          cura])
enemy = Person(1200, 65, 45, 25, [])

running = True
i = 0

print(bcolors.FAIL + bcolors.BOLD + "AN ENEMY ATTACKS!" + bcolors.ENDC)

while running:
print("=================")
player.choose_action()
choice = input("Choose action")
index = int(choice) - 1

if index == 0:
    dmg = player.generate_damage()
    enemy.take_damage(dmg)
    print("You attacked for", dmg, "points of damage.")
elif index == 1:
    player.choose_magic()
    magic_choice = int(input("Choose magic:")) - 1

    spell = player.magic[magic_choice]
    magic_dmg = spell.generate_damage()

    current_mp = player.get_mp()

    if spell.cost > current_mp:
        print(bcolors.FAIL + "\nNot enough MP\n" + bcolors.ENDC)
        continue

    player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)

    if spell.type == "white":
        player.heal(magic_dmg)
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + " heals for", str(magic_dmg), "HP." + bcolors.ENDC)
    elif spell.type == "black":
        enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
        print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + " deals", str(magic_dmg), "points of damage." + bcolors.ENDC)


enemy_choice = 1

enemy_dmg = enemy.generate_damage()
player.take_damage(enemy_dmg)
print("Enemy attacks for", enemy_dmg)

print("-----------------------")
print("Enemy HP:", bcolors.FAIL + str(enemy.get_hp()) + "/" + str(enemy.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")

print("Your HP:", bcolors.OKGREEN + str(player.get_hp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_hp()) + bcolors.ENDC)
print("Your MP:", bcolors.OKBLUE + str(player.get_mp()) + "/" + str(player.get_max_mp()) + bcolors.ENDC + "\n")

if enemy.get_hp() == 0:
    print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "You win!" + bcolors.ENDC)
    running = False
elif player.get_hp() == 0:
    print(bcolors.FAIL + "Your enemy has defeated you!" + bcolors.ENDC)
    running = False
```

Person class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp, mp, atk, df, magic):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp
        self.maxmp = mp
        self.mp = mp
        self.atkl = atk - 10
        self.atkh = atk + 10
        self.df = df
        self.magic = magic
        self.actions = ["Attack", "Magic"]

            def generate_damage(self):
    return random.randrange(self.atkl, self.atkh)


def take_damage(self, dmg):
    self.hp -= dmg
    if self.hp < 0:
        self.hp = 0


    def heal(self, dmg):
        self.hp += dmg
        if self.hp > self.maxhp:
            self.hp = self.maxhp

def get_hp(self):
    return self.hp

def get_max_hp(self):
    return self.maxhp

def get_mp(self):
    return self.mp

def get_max_mp(self):
    return self.maxmp

def reduce_mp(self, cost):
    self.mp -= cost


def choose_action(self):
    i = 1
    print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Actions" + bcolors.ENDC)
    for item in self.actions:
        print(str(i) + ":", item)
        i += 1

def choose_magic(self):
    i = 1

    print(bcolors.OKBLUE + bcolors.BOLD + "Magic" + bcolors.ENDC)
    for spell in self.magic:
        print(str(i) + ":", spell.name, "(cost:", str(spell.cost) + ")")
        i += 1
```

Comment: The error says that `Person` does not know how to be `.heal`ed, so you should show us how you defined the class `Person`.

Comment: If that in your comment is the entire class. then the problem is obviously that you never `def heal(self, amount)`. Also, please make this an edit in the question itself.

Comment: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43206556/edit) the post and don't post multi line code in comments, which is utterly unreadable :)

Comment: @tobias_k I'm struggling to understand what you mean. I do apologise this coding m'larky is coming slowly to me but I'm hoping to persevere!

Comment: @kazemakase Your help is apprectiated.

Comment: RIP I still have no idea what to do lmao

Comment: What he means is that if you want to be able to `player.heal()`, then you need to have a `def heal(self, ...):` method in your Person class. Otherwise, Python doesn't have any idea how to `heal()` a Person.

Comment: @glibdud check my recent edit, this was already in my code and I believe this what you're saying was wrong. Yet I am getting that error code.

Comment: Is that how your code is actually indented? Because if so, then `heal()` is defined in the `take_damage` function, not the Person class.

Comment: @glibdud yeah that is how my code is indented, so how do I got about defining it in the Person class?

Comment: @LewisShaw Have you refreshed the page? There are already two answers, both telling you how to fix the problem, I think.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it was such a simple mistake and I can't believe I didn't understand it. After staring at my code blankly I saw the mistake you guys were so clearly pointing out to me. Apologies for my idiocrisy. I'll be on my way to finish up my coding for today.

Comment: @LewisShaw This indentation stuff can be tricky in the beginning. Still, nice job so far, if you really are the newbie you claim to be. :)

Comment: @kazemakase Thank you and thank you for the help. I have a little bit of knowledge in HTML and CSS but apart from that I only have about 4-5 hours of practice and learning in Python, I'm really motivated to do a lot more and increase the amount of languages I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just saw that the question was edited.
**The problem is indentation.** All method `def` statements should start at the same indentation level as `__init__` otherwise they are not part of the class.

(Indentation means how many spaces you put in the beginning of a code line.)

---

First, let me reduce your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp

player = Person(460)
player.hp = 455  # forcefully reduce player's hp
player.heal(10)  # AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'heal'
```

Well, it's pretty obvious that the `player` Person does not really know how to be healed. `heal` was never defined. Note that the `.hp` could be accessed without problems because it was defined in `__init__`.

`heal` should not be a simple attribute, because we want to call it. So it should be a *method*, that is a function associated to a class. It can be defined like that, for example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, hp):
        self.maxhp = hp
        self.hp = hp

    # This is part of the Person class
    def heal(self, amount):
        self.hp += amount

# This is NOT part of the Person class
def something():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the implemantation of the Person class. I'm guessing that you dont have an attribute declared "heal". I think that you are trying to call a method from the class Person ( def heal(damage=0) )

Basically attributes are the classes fields. for example

```
class Example():
    field1 = [] # this is an attribute
    health = 1000 # this is an attribute

    def __init__(): # this is a method
        field1 = ['a', 'b']

    def heal(value=0): #this is a method
         if self.health < 1000:
             if value > 1000 - self.health:
                 self.health = 1000 - self.health
             else:
                 self.health += value
```

I've written a simple heal method so you can see what I'm talking about.

So if you want to call an attribute you dont use the "(...)" on the instance of a class. You just call "my_instance.attribute1". But if you want to call a method you should use the "(...)" like "my_instance.my_method()". (Again, we are not talking about advanced python programming for example the @property decorator with can be used to call a method as an attribute).

Edit:
The heal method is seen only in the take_damage method. It is a local function.